# Forcefully full screen Youtube Player IOS

Tags: youtube

I am trying to forcefully trigger the full screen in youtube player. I am following the Youtube Player Frame API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I can't make the video full screen on click of the button. But no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you in this application (https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/la-nucia-tv/id982784095?mt=8). I solved it using a webview and inserting there the youtube embed code.

I know that it isn't a perfect solution, but it worked for my customer.

Comment: We are doing the same. The Youtube API does it the same way which you said. We embed the youtube Iframe in the web view. Our web view is having a specific frame and is not full screen. First we are displaying it as inline. And there is no function which we can use to make the player fullscreen.